# After session out, the previous user's credentials are there in page instead of current user in Angular 5

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular5

In angular 5, when I logged out from one user and login from another user it is showing the previous user's credentials instead of current user's until I refresh the page. I am using `localstorage.clear()` method. Still not working.

Here it is login function

```
 login(userLogin: LoginModel) {
    const objectToSend = JSON.stringify(userLogin);

     const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('withCredentials', 'true');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    return this.http.post( this.appURL+'/api/auth/login', objectToSend, { headers: headers }).pipe(
      map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

        const response_token = response.json();
        console.log(response_token);
        const accessToken = response_token.auth_token;

        if (accessToken == null) {
          throw new Error('Received accessToken was empty');
        }

       // let refreshToken: string = response_token.refresh_token;
        const expiresIn: number = response_token.expires_in;

        const tokenExpiryDate = new Date();
        tokenExpiryDate.setSeconds(tokenExpiryDate.getSeconds() + expiresIn);

        const accessTokenExpiry = tokenExpiryDate;
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', response_token.auth_token);
        localStorage.setItem('role', response_token.role);

        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);

        this.router.navigate(['/orderhistory']);
        return true;

      }));
  }
```

And is logout function

```
logout() {

  localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
  localStorage.removeItem('role');
  localStorage.clear();
  sessionStorage.clear();

  this.loggedIn = false;
  this._authNavStatusSource.next(false);

}
```

this is the component where user role is not updating accordingly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.scss']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  currentRole: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService, private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      quantity: [null, Validators.required],
      prescription: [null],

    });
    this.currentRole = this.userService.Role;


  }

and this is the template. and this role is not updating after logout

 <form [formGroup]="form" class="form-horizontal">
          <span *ngIf="currentRole =='administrator'">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Client Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="col-form-label">{{orderModel.clientName}}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span>{{currentRole}}</span>
<form>
```

Comment: Please show (copy-paste here or link to, say, github gist) the login form, and perhaps the login service or whatever object holds those stale user credentials, so we can help debug.

Comment: through response token i am getting the current user at login and setting it in localstorage item.at that time it is showing correct information.may be it is browser cache problem.

Comment: Maybe, but in my experience, it is likely not browser problem, but your code specific. But please do provide the code you use, so we can look and be certain. Otherwise your question is not really answerable, maybe read on how to ask good questions?

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippet

Comment: You need to provide one more bit: where are you showing your user data? We need that component too. For example, I would say that you do not update that component that there's been a change when you logout (until you reload the page). Usually you'd do that by also having a `user$: BehaviorSubject<User>` on your login service. Then when you log in or log out, you update it (`this.user$.next(newValue)`). Your components would then get immediately notified of the change in user data and this is most likely your issue.

Comment: Btw, if you provide the code of the component where you're showing the stale user data (both template and class), we might give you a more complete answer, as a proper answer and not a comment.

Comment: I have updated the question with desired code. Please check out.

Comment: Hi Anjali, welcome to StackOverflow! Firstly, could you please provide a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ so that we can help you (for example, as what Zlatko has stated above: provide a Stackblitz, Github project, etc.). Secondly, have you ever heard of _[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)_? This can reduce the amount of string concatenation. Thanks!

Comment: The problem was in the service.. i replaced my code this.currentRole = this.userService.Role to this.currentRole =  localStorage.getItem('role') and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing local storage and I suspect you'll be able to confirm in Chrome Developer Tools (Application tab) that the values have been cleared, which is why refreshing the page works.

What you're seeing on the screen is the result of values you still have stored in either your component or service.

My usual logout flow is something like this:

1. Clear browser state (what you did).
2. Clear the relevant service values. I usually manage the active user in a service called `UserService` and when signing out, the service also clears out fields like the active user's name or user ID or anything else stored here.
3. Navigate away. While signed in, the user is usually able to view values that should not be available after signing out. So I use the `Router` service to navigate to a page where the user can sign in again. For an app where most actions require a signed-in user, that's enough.

My steps 2 and 3 are what clears the screen so stale values are no longer shown. Step 1 really prevents the app from thinking the user still has a valid session.

Comment: The problem was in the service.. i replaced my code this.currentRole = this.userService.Role to this.currentRole =  localStorage.getItem('role') and it is working fine now. thanks :)

Comment: Does that actually fix the problem? The value in the service is still wrong. I would imagine that the better fix is to simply update the value in the service at the same time as you update local storage.

Comment: Yes it does. Because i am updating localstorage on login and logout. so i should have retrieved it direct from localstorage not from the backend service.Actually at the time of login i am setting the key of localstorage from authentication service as i have mentioned in my question, so thats why i do not need to get it from other services.